# Powershell: Exception calling "AttachDatabase" with "3" argument(s)

Tags: powershell, smo

I 'm trying to backup the mdf file using the following approach but the script fails when attaching the database back to the server. I have started facing this issue in our new server (Windows Server 2008 R2). The following is the scriplet.

```
#load assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null

write-host "Initializing..."
#Initialization section
$serverName = "sqlserver\SQL2005"
$databaseName = "myDatabase"
$sourceLocation = "\\sqlserver\dbPath\myDatabase"
$attachDBSourceLocation = "D:\Sql 2005 Databases\dbPath\myDatabase"
$mdfFileName = $sourceLocation + "\" + $databaseName + ".mdf"
$attachMDFFileName = $attachDBSourceLocation + "\" + $databaseName + ".mdf"
$ldfFileName = $sourceLocation + "\" + $databaseName + "_log.ldf"
$destLocation = read-host -prompt "Enter the destination location"
#End of Initialization section
write-host "Initialization completed"

#create a new server object
$serverConn = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection")
$serverName, "psuser", "psuser"
$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $serverConn 
write-host "Server object created"

$server.Databases["myDatabase"].ExecuteNonQuery("ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionTypes]::Default)

#detach the database to be copied. Drop connections if any by changing the connection mode to single user mode
$server.DetachDatabase($databaseName, $true)
write-host "Database $databaseName detached"

#copy the database (backup)
write-host "Started copying database '$mdfFileName' to '$destLocation'. Please wait..."
copy-item $mdfFileName -Destination $destLocation
write-host "Database '$databaseName' copied to '$destLocation'"

#delete the log file
remove-item -path $ldfFileName
write-host "Database LDF file deleted" #attach the mdf file without ldf so that a new ldf is automatically created
write-host "Attaching Database '$databaseName'. Please wait..."
$strColl = New-Object ("System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection")
[void]$strColl.Add($attachMDFFileName)
$server.AttachDatabase($databaseName, $strColl, [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AttachOptions]::NewBroker)
write-host "Database attached successfully"

write-host "Shrinking Database '$databaseName'. Please wait..."
$server.Databases[$databaseName].ExecuteNonQuery("DBCC SHRINKDATABASE ($databaseName, 5)")

write-host "Database shrinked successfully"
write-host "Database backup successful"
```

Comment: When you need troubleshooting it's useful if you post the error you obtain. You can edit your question and add details.

Comment: Is this line a typo? `$serverConn write-host "Server object created"` It does not make any sense to me..

Comment: Thanks empo. Corrected the script. $serverConn is a parameter for server class. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: So, this was the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need that attachmentoptions overload? From the overload list for that method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.attachdatabase(v=SQL.90).aspx

it doesn't appear that you need to specify that if you're re-attaching an existing database, just the database name and the file collection.

Comment: Hi mjolinor, to attach back a database, it requires us to specify the name of the database (first parameter), path (second parameter) and optionally if you want to enable the broker (third parameter). This worked for me with Windows Server 2003. Not sure why it is failing now with Windows Server 2008 R2. Any thoughts on what i 'm missing?

Comment: Usually when stuff that worked on 2003 quits working on 2008 R2 I suspect UAC. Are you running the script with elevated permissions?